# Vue JS data availability among components

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2

I've just stared playing with vueJS inside a laravel app.

I am trying to create a steps wizard and I'm having trouble accessing data from the vue definition inside one of the components.

I have:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

data: {
    currentstep : 1,
    ...
    chosenName: "",
```

And I would like to be able to access `chosenName` inside
`Vue.component('step-controls', {`

so that

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="nextStep()" :disabled="secondstep" v-if="firststep != true && laststep != true">Next</button>
```

Would be disabled if the value of `chosenName` is `empty string`

I would have imagined that it should be something like :

```
 secondstep: function() {
      return (this.currentstep == 2 && this.chosenName =='')
 },
```

but `chosenName` is not one of the `props`. If I am adding it to the `props` array, how do I keep it in sync?

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/angelin8r/oxse2p3v/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your fiddle, made the following changes

```
<step-controls
    v-for="step in steps"
    :step="step"
    :stepcount="steps.length"
    :currentstep="currentstep"
    @step-change="stepChanged"
    :chosen-name="chosenName">
</step-controls>
```

and

```
props: ['step', 'stepcount', 'currentstep','chosenName'],
```

By binding `chosenName` to the parent property, it will automatically update when the parent's property updates.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Works like a charm! I now wonder how does changing data to a function gonna affect my code ? https://jsfiddle.net/angelin8r/oxse2p3v/

Comment: @AngelinCalu When creating a new Vue, you need not use a function. You need to use a function when you are creating a component (like with Vue.component). The reason for the difference is because when you are using a component you generally want to isolate the state because you may use the component more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that the data property of your Vue element needs to be a function. That function will return an object with your currentStep and currentName. [See the docs for reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

So, your component would look like

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      currentStep : 1,
      chosenName: "",
    };
  },
})
```

Then, you can access and update the data with `this.currentStep` or `this.chosenName`

Comment: I have tried what you suggested. Still cannot access `chosenName` with `console.log(this.chosenName);` inside the component. Could you add the solution in the fiddle ?